# GETing a list of urls in a async fashion in GO

Tags: go

I my GO application, I often need to query a list or urls.  As GO is async from ground up, it is the perfect place to use this functionality.

What is the best way solve that?  I found a [blog](http://matt.aimonetti.net/posts/2012/11/27/real-life-concurrency-in-go/) proposing a solution but it fails with an empty list of urls.

Thanks!

Comment: If you add a `if len(urls) == 0 { return [] }` to the beginning of that method, it would work, right?

Comment: yes, but is there a way to have something nicer? I javascript I would use promises and the *all* function.  What about Go?  What is the best practice.  Because the blog solution works but is not nice.

Comment: You could also move the `if len(responses) == len(urls) {return responses }` to just above the `select`.  That should also cause an almost immediate exit when `len(urls) == 0`.

Comment: You say "Go is async from the ground up" but this is a misunderstanding. Go is *concurrent* from the ground up, based on the principles of CSP. With this, you can do both blocking and non-blocking I/O. The example in the blog uses blocking channels without guilt, with goroutines providing concurrency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tweaked the code in the blog link you provided and made it slightly more resilient to error.

The code below should compile, and should handle boundary cases such as an empty input `urls` slice.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "time"
)

const timeout time.Duration = 3 * time.Second

var urls = []string{
    "http://golang.org/",
    "http://stackoverflow.com/",
    "http://i.wanta.pony/", // Should error
}

type httpResponse struct {
    url      string
    response *http.Response
    err      error
}

func asyncHTTPGets(urls []string, ch chan *httpResponse) {
    for _, url := range urls {
        go func(url string) {
            resp, err := http.Get(url)
            ch <- &httpResponse{url, resp, err}
        }(url)
    }
}

func main() {
    responseCount := 0
    ch := make(chan *httpResponse)
    go asyncHTTPGets(urls, ch)
    for responseCount != len(urls) {
        select {
        case r := <-ch:
            if r.err != nil {
                fmt.Printf("Error %s fetching %s\n", r.err, r.url)
            } else {
                fmt.Printf("%s was fetched\n", r.url)
            }
            responseCount++
        case <-time.After(timeout):
            os.Exit(1)
        }
    }
}
```

[Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/PveWh9wzes)

Comment: I love this answer!, however, it has no error handling

Comment: should all questions on SO have error handling? ( I worry about people who may mistakenly copy-paste and introduce bugs in their system...)

Answer (score 0):

since you are using unbuffered channel, it's will be blocked until the url has been processed.